# How to display <div> content based on Radio button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I Want to display `<div class="Add1">` content based on `<div class="delivery">` selection. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
<div class="delivery">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="false" checked />
        <span>Deliver my order to me</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="true"  />
        <span>I will pick up my order</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="true" />
        <span>I will pick</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="Add1">
 <div>Order address</div>

  <div>Order </div>

   <div>Order me</div>

</div>
```

The `JQuery` is:

```
var address = $('.Add1');
$('.delivery input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
     if ($(this).val() === 'false') {
        address.hide();
    }
   else if ($(this).val() === 'true') {
        address.show();
    } else {
        address.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You have 2 radio buttons with `value="true"` which does not make sense. And which `<div>`'s are you referring to - the ones inside `<div class="Add1">` element?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I was testing the above code so had put like this. And inside` <div>` class, I am having 3 `<div>` elements. Based on radio button selection, it will display.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I was referring your fiddle and was trying to work around this with 3 radio buttons and 3 text.` http://jsfiddle.net/sfw0g2a7/1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by giving each of the `<div>` elements in `id` attribute

```
<div class="Add1">
    <div id="A">Order address</div>
    <div id="B">Order</div>
    <div id="C">Order me</div>
</div>
```

and add a `data` attribute to your radio buttons matching the appropriate `id`.

```
<div class="delivery">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="false" data-divid="A" checked />
        <span>Deliver my order to me</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="true" data-divid="B" />
        <span>I will pick up my order</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="DeliveryChoice" value="true" data-divid="C" />
        <span>I will pick</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Then the script becomes

```
var divs = $('.Add1').children('div');
$('.delivery input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('divid');
    divs.hide(); // hide all
    $('#' + id).show();
});
```

and style your 2nd and 3rd divs as hidden initially

```
.Add1 div:not(:first-of-type) {
  display:none;
}
```

Refer [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwr6qvuj/)